# switchMap Type void is not assignable to type ObservableInput<{}>

Tags: angular, rxjs

Im using Angular http and RXJS to retrieve some application settings. The http uses RXJS shareReplay to avoid multiple of the same calls.

This is working as expected, and inspecting the Networks tab i can see only 1 call to my backend API.

Some components within my app, will call the service and use the result to render the page. Other components, need to call the service like above, but then do 'something' with the result again, e.g more http calls and then render the page. When attempting to do the later, i get type error:

```
Argument of type '(result: any) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: any, index: number)' => ObservableInput<{}>
```

Over my switchMap use.

-- Working simple example without switchMap ----

cart.component.ts

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.systemPreferences.getPreferences()
        .subscribe(
            (result: any) => {
                this.headerTitle = result.title || '';
            },
            (err) => {
                console.log('there has been an error');
            },
            () => // Some completion code
        );
}
```

systemPreferences.service.ts:

```
const CACHE_SIZE = 1;

export class SystemPreferences {
    private $cache: Observable<Object>

    private requestConfig() {
         return this.http.get("/api/some/endpoint").pipe(
             map(response => response.value)
         );
    }

    public getPreferences() {
        if (!this.cache$) {
            this.cache$ = this.requestConfig().pipe(
             shareReplay(CACHE_SIZE)
            );
        }

        return this.cache$;
    }
}
```

/api/some/endpoint example response:

```
{
    "appName": "Tables Forks and Spoons",
    "title": "My title",
    "regionUrls": [
        "http://www.region1.com:8021",
        "http://www.region2.com:8021",
        "http://www.region3.com:8021",
        "http://www.region4.com:8021"
    ],
    "nonRegionUrls": [
        "http://www.non-region1.com:8021",
        "http://www.non-region2.com:8021",
        "http://www.non-region3.com:8021",
        "http://www.non-region4.com:8021"
    ]
}
```

-- Type error simple example wit switchMap ----

cart.component.ts

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.systemPreferences.getPreferences()
        .pipe(
            .switchMap((result: any) => {

               this.systemPreferences.getLiveUrl(result['regionUrls']);

            }))
        .subscribe(
            (result: any) => {
                this.liveLink = result.liveLink; // result.livelink is added as part of this.systemPreferences.getLiveUrl above
                this.headerTitle = result.title || '';
            },
            (err) => {
                console.log('there has been an error');
            }
        );
}
```

systemPreferences.service.ts:

```
const CACHE_SIZE = 1;

export class SystemPreferences {
    private $cache: Observable<Object>

    private requestConfig() {
         return this.http.get("/api/some/endpoint").pipe(
             map(response => response.value)
         );
    }

    public getPreferences() {
        if (!this.cache$) {
            this.cache$ = this.requestConfig().pipe(
             shareReplay(CACHE_SIZE)
            );
        }

        return this.cache$;
    }

    public getLiveUrl(urls: any) {
        let promises = [];

        urls.forEach((url) => {
           promises.push(this.http.get(url + 'some/endpoint/')); 
        });

        const results = forkJoin(promises) {
            .subscribe((data: any) => {
                return this.getBest(data);
            }
        }
    }

    public getBest(data: any) {
        // Loops through data, and returns a single URL as a string
        // 'http//www.thebesturltouse.com'
    }
}
```

---

Update:

Trying to return a second observable as suggested, see below, has the same type void error as above.

cart.component.ts

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.systemPreferences.getPreferences()
        .pipe(
            .switchMap((result: any) => {
               return this.systemPreferences.getLiveUrl(result['regionUrls']);
            }))
        .subscribe(
            (result: any) => {
                this.liveLink = result.liveLink; // result.livelink is added as part of this.systemPreferences.getLiveUrl above
                this.headerTitle = result.title || '';
            },
            (err) => {
                console.log('there has been an error');
            }
        );
}
```

systemPreferences.service.ts:

```
const CACHE_SIZE = 1;

export class SystemPreferences {
    private $cache: Observable<Object>
    private $switchObs: Observable<Object> 

    private requestConfig() {
         return this.http.get("/api/some/endpoint").pipe(
             map(response => response.value)
         );
    }

    public getPreferences() {
        if (!this.cache$) {
            this.cache$ = this.requestConfig().pipe(
             shareReplay(CACHE_SIZE)
            );
        }

        return this.cache$;
    }

    public getLiveUrl(urls: any) {
        let promises = [];

        urls.forEach((url) => {
           promises.push(this.http.get(url + 'some/endpoint/')); 
        });

        const results = forkJoin(promises) {
            .subscribe((data: any) => {
                this.$switchObs = this.getBest(data);
                return this.$switchObs;
            }
        }
    }

    public getBest(data: any) {
        // Loops through data, and returns a single URL as a string
        // 'http//www.thebesturltouse.com'
    }
}
```

---

Update to multiple switchMaps

cart.component.ts

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.systemPreferences.getPreferences()
        .pipe(
            .switchMap((result: any) => {
               return this.systemPreferences.getLiveUrl(result['regionUrls']);
            }),
            .switchMap((liveRegion: any) => {
               return this.systemPreferences.getBest(liveRegion);
            }))
        .subscribe(
            (bestUrl: String) => {
                console.log('best');
                console.log(bestUrl);
            },
            (err) => {
                console.log('there has been an error');
            }
        );
}
```

systemPreferences.service.ts:

```
const CACHE_SIZE = 1;

export class SystemPreferences {
    private $cache: Observable<Object>
    private $switchObs: Observable<String> 

    private requestConfig() {
         return this.http.get("/api/some/endpoint").pipe(
             map(response => response.value)
         );
    }

    public getPreferences() {
        if (!this.cache$) {
            this.cache$ = this.requestConfig().pipe(
             shareReplay(CACHE_SIZE)
            );
        }

        return this.cache$;
    }

    public getLiveUrl(urls: any) {
        let promises = [];

        urls.forEach((url) => {
           promises.push(this.http.get(url + 'some/endpoint/')); 
        });

        return forkJoin(promises);
    }

    public getBest(data: any) {
        // Loops through data, and returns a single URL as a string
        // 
        return this.$switchObs; // = 'http//www.thebesturltouse.com'
    }
}
```

With the above, on the console.log('best')/console.log(bestUrl), i see:

```
'best'
h
'best'
t
'best'
t
'best'
p
'best'
:
'best'
/
'best'
/
'best'
w
'best'
w
'best'
w
'best'
.
'best'
b
etc etc etc
```

Rather than just the string http//www.thebesturltouse.com

---

Update.

Within the multi switchMap example, if i return Obserbable.of(this.$switchObs); i get the expected single string URL.

This doesnt feel like the best way to solve this.

Comment: Just on an overlook, you need to return the second `observable` from within `switchMap`

Comment: @xyz - sorry, 'the' second observable? or 'a' second observable?

Comment: 'the' second observable. Have a return in `switchMap`(), like:  `return this.systemPreferences.getLiveUrl(result['regionUrls']);`

Comment: @xyz - see update section, tried your recommendation, same issue/error. See new private $switchObs: Observable<Object>  too

Comment: return `results` from `getLiveUrl()`

Comment: @xyz - perhaps i am doing too much in my switchMap too? may be a better solution is multiple switchMaps? so, 1 switchMap that performs the forkJoin, and 2 to do getBest. Would be better/easier to write unit tests too.

Comment: Also returning anything from subscription of `forkjoin` will not help, use `map` instead of `subscribe` if you want to manipulate the returned observable

Comment: @xyz update example when using multiple switchMaps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not related to the `switchMap` operator itself. It's rather the fact that your `getLiveUrl`method is of type void. switchMap expects a function that returns an observable as input parameter. So you want `getLiveUrl` to return an observable. To achieve this the code could look like this (do note I'm not 100% sure what `getBest` is actually doing, this may effect the solution.):

```
 public getLiveUrl(urls: any) {
        let promises = [];

        urls.forEach((url) => {
           promises.push(this.http.get(url + 'some/endpoint/')); 
        });

        return forkJoin(promises).pipe(
           map(data => this.getBest(data))
        );
    }
```

I'm still not 100% sure what you are actually trying to achieve but I hope this helps you.